# Higher than expected outgoing bandwidth

Tags: google-app-engine

We have an application which is experiencing much higher outgoing bandwidth than we would expect given the loads. We have over 10 GB/day of outgoing bandwidth with essentially 0 visitors/day on the front end and a bunch of back end processing (using backend servers and the task queue). We also use memcache.

Google says they bill as follows:

```
Outgoing Bandwidth (billable)
The amount of data sent by the application in response to requests.
This includes:
    data served in response to both secure requests and non-secure requests by application     servers, static file servers, or the Blobstore
    data sent in email messages
    data sent over XMPP or the Channel API
    data in outgoing HTTP requests sent by the URL fetch service.
```

We are not serving static files (it only has a rest api), don't use the blob store, don't send emails, don't use XMPP. We do use the URL fetch service, but only with GET requests. I find it hard to believe that 6000 GET requests would amount to 10 GBs of data.

Does anyone know how I can track down the details of what goes into our outgoing bandwidth usage?

Answer (score 0):

To get an idea of when this bandwidth is being consumed, on the appengine dashboard you can change the charts context to: Traffic (Bytes/Second)

Also, within the dashboard I would open the Quota Details page and give it a quick once over and see if you can isolate which service is consuming the bandwidth.

On a side note, have you reviewed tasks in flight to see if perhaps something is stuck in a queue?